# Maven pom dependencies between app and common

Tags: maven, pom.xml

Every applications has its own pom.xml  and root has its own pom.xml. common is in every web app and it has its own pom.xml.  I want to get different values from common pom.xml based on webapp loads. For instance common should give value1 for web-ap1 and same common should give value2 for web-app2.  How should i get different value from common pom  ?

```
 my-project
      + pom.xml
      +-- common
         + pom.xml
      +-- web-app-1
         + pom.xml
      +-- web-app-2
          + pom.xml ?
```

Comment: value1  and value2 are properties in pom.xml?

Comment: properties are in common pom or in web-app pom ?

Comment: I dont understand your question ?

Comment: Yes. value1 and value2 are properties in pom.xml